# How do I display changing time within a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, silverlight, textblock, stopwatch

So I have a stopwatch and all I want is for it to be display on a textblock. How can I do that?

Comment: Are we talking WPF or Silverlight, or????

Answer (score 4):

Create a TimerViewModel, that looks something like this:

```
public class TimerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TimerViewModel()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
        startTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private DispatcherTimer timer;
    private DateTime startTime;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public TimeSpan TimeFromStart { get { return DateTime.Now - startTime; } }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("TimeFromStart");
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Instantiate it like so in your code-behind:

```
public partial class TimerPage : UserControl
{
    public TimerPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timerViewModel = new TimerViewModel();
        DataContext = timerViewModel;
    }

    private TimerViewModel timerViewModel;
}
```

And then bind it like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeFromStart}" />
</Grid>
```

Works like a charm.  You'll need to modify the basic concept a bit I'm sure, but the basic idea of having a DispatcherTimer fire the PropertyChanged notification is what's key.

Answer (score 1):

The [TimerTextBlock](http://koderhack.blogspot.com/2011/04/wpf-silverlight-timer-textblock.html) is used to display the elapsed time in a TextBlock and updates the time elapsed after every second. I think you will have to modify it to act as a stop watch.

Answer (score 0):

A [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) is used for measurement between two points in time. It does not emit any kind of event that might drive a binding. You need to use some sort of [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) (the link assumes WPF... other options are available... update your tags) in your model to create change notifications.

Comment: basically when they pressed a button the Stopwatch start's and when they hit the other one the stopwatch stop. But I want to display the elapsed time to them on a textblock.